# Usage and examples of もの（それに相当する）

Tags: grammar

In this website

https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=37978

it is shown a usage of もの that says as follows.

それに相当する
特定の語について、その状態に達している、その状態に相当することを表します。

However, I don't quite understand the examples associated with this usage (sentences 6-8).

（６）　子供が大怪我しちゃって、一時は本当に冷や汗ものだった。

（７）　エイズを治療する薬が開発されたらノーベル賞ものだ。

（８）　「簡単に儲けられますよ」という眉唾ものの投資話には騙されないようにしましょう。

While in sentence 7, I think ものだ can be understood as "to deserve (a Nobel prize)", **I don't understand the function of もの in sentences 6 and 8. What kind of nuance does もの give to 冷や汗 and to 眉唾?**

Also, if possible, **could you please give me other examples with もの with the usage それに相当する (to correspond, to be equivalent to)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The もの adds exactly the nuance of '相当する', i.e., something that is equivalent to the thing but not the thing itself. E.g. ノーベル賞もの says it *deserves* a Nobel prize, and doesn't say that a Nobel prize is actually awarded.

A translation that comes to my mind is *that could lead to*, even if not very idiomatic in English.

- 冷や汗もの： something that would make you (could lead to) cold sweat
- ノーベル賞もの： something that could result in a Nobel prize
- 眉唾もの：something that would make you [眉に唾をつける](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9C%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%B0)

Instances that come off the top of my head are:

- 噴飯もの：*absurd*. (thing that makes you laugh and spit up things in the mouth)
- 表彰もの：*award-worthy*
- 懲罰もの：*a thing that potentially results in a punishment* (E.g., 三日も遅刻したら懲罰ものだ）